# Netlogo- Average Path Length

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a netlogo program in which turtles move around randomly and create links with each other when they cross the same patch. I would like to implement the average path length of the network after a certain number of ticks.

I have got as far as the turtles creating links but am unsure how to implement an average minimum path length. How would I go about implementing this and showing it on a monitor?

Comment: You should show what you have tried.

Comment: Look at the networks extension and, in particular, the `nw:mean-path-length` primitive. Calculating mean path length is computationally expensive, don't write your own procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the networks extension and, in particular, the `nw:mean-path-length` primitive. Calculating mean path length is computationally expensive, don't write your own procedure.